# wuauclt.exe /updatenow does not install important updates via command line

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, automation

I am trying to update windows OS using command line - wuauclt.exe /updatenow. But I have to run this everytime after every reboot and it does not install important updates that windows is suggesting. Is their a way to update windows and reboot until it is fully updated via command line?

Comment: See: https://superuser.com/questions/1061931/wuauclt-exe-detectnow-updatenow-not-installing-all-updates

Comment: I tried this. It does not work. I am able to install regular updates but when an update is a part of important update it does not install via command line.